# (Lam Prop 5.6) R $\subseteq S$, then under what condition rad(S) $\cap$ R $\subseteq$ rad (R)?

Tags: noncommutative-algebra

***The condition given in the text is $_{R}R$ direct summand of $_{R}S$.***

But I think I don't need this condition because if  x $\in$ rad(S) $\cap$ R, then for all y $\in$ S, 1-xy is left invertible (property of rad(S)), but since R $\subseteq$ S, this is equally true for y $\in$ R and hence x $\in$ rad(R).

Comment: It's silly to reference a book without naming the book, especially with an author with lots of books like Lam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1-xy$ is right invertible *by an element of $S$*, but why should that element happen to be in $R$? Maybe there aren't any right inverses in$R$ after all!

That is the gap in the reasoning you gave.